# Elasticsearch vm.max_map_count error in docker image on MacOS 14

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have the "vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]" error while elastic container starting on Docker 4.25, MacOS 14 and ARM core.

Here is my container props:

```
image: elasticsearch:8.9.0
container_name: elasticsearch
hostname: elastic
environment:
  - node.name=elasticsearch
  - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
  - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
  - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
  - 'ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
volumes:
  - es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
ports:
  - ${DC_ELASTIC_HOST_PORT}:${DC_ELASTIC_PORT}
```

I've tried the steps described here: [Install Elasticsearch with Docker](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-vm-max-map-count-error-in-docker-image-on-macos-14/346285)
But it does not helps.

command `docker-machine ssh` fails by `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists` . Seems to vm machine must be created, but it requires VirtualBox that runs only on Intel core Macs.

command `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` fails due to path not found.

command `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` fails by `sysctl: unknown oid 'vm.max_map_count'`error too.

May be somebody knows any another solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the only thing possible right now is to downgrade back to 4.24.2 (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4242) for MacOS.

I don't know if it has something to do with the Rosetta implementation or not; try doing the software update for Rosetta (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/#system-requirements) and see if that helps.

This is not the answer right now, but it is a temporary work around.

Comment: I was having the exact same problem and tried the exact same remedies as OP after updating Docker Desktop to 2.25.0, and I can confirm that going back to the previous 2.24 release has fixed it - thanks for this 

Comment: It looks like they have updated this as of 4.25.1 (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4251)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, Elasticsearch requires the `vm.max_map_count` setting to be set to at least `262144`. On macOS, Docker Desktop runs a virtualized Linux environment where the Elasticsearch container is actually running. Adjusting settings like `vm.max_map_count` within this environment can be challenging because it's not as straightforward as on a native Linux host.

- Before making this change, make sure Docker Desktop is not running.
- You'll need to edit the Docker Desktop configuration file directly. You can find this file at `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json`. Open this file with a text editor.
- In the `settings.json` file, look for the `"linuxVmSettings"` or similar section, and you may need to add or modify an entry for `vm.max_map_count`. If it's not there, you can try to add something like this:

```
"linuxVmSettings": {
  "vm.max_map_count": 262144
}
```

Save the changes to `settings.json` and start Docker Desktop again.

Comment: Tried this but as soon as Docker Desktop opens, it removes that setting from the file and I'm no further forward, unfortunately